# cmd truncates first lines of ouput

Tags: c, windows, windows-7, cmd, codeblocks

I'm debugging a program that could potentially have up to 20,000 lines output. The command prompt appears to truncate and only show the last 1000 so I can't see the ouptput the program gave at the begining. How can I fix this so I can scroll all the way up to the point where I run the program? I'm using Windows 7 and Codeblocks IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run cmd (as admin), go to Properties->Layout tab and increase the Screen buffer size to what you want, and enable "Apply these properties for future windows".

Another option, just to check the output: Have it written to a file and read it later.